# How do I use an Enum in another Java class?

Tags: java, enums

I have a Java file which is solely an enum:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    ONE, TWO, THREE;
}
```

And I want to access this enum in a different file e.g. `MyClass.java`. Do I use `MyEnum.TWO`, or what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exactly. You can do such:

```
MyEnum x = MyEnum.TWO;
```

Don't forget to import `MyEnum` if it is in another package.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. for example:

```
MyEnum enumVar = MyEnum.TWO;
```